# The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini but the file is smaller than limit

Tags: php

i have simple script for upload files, if i upload file <500Kb everything is working fine, but when i upload bigger file $_FILES['upload']['error'] return me 1.
I know that mean file exceeds the upload_max_filesize, but i set in .htacces php_value post_max_size 999999M and check ini_get('post_max_size') return me 999999M.
But script still don't work with file ~4MB let alone bigger file.

At the end, sorry for my eng (is not main basic lang)

Answer (score 1):

By default, the maximum upload file size for PHP scripts is set to 128 megabytes. However, you may want to change these limits. You can set a limit by changing the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size directives in your php.ini file.

To ensure that file uploads work correctly, the post_max_size directive should be a little larger than the upload_max_filesize. For example, the following settings demonstrate how to set a file upload limit to 20 megabytes:

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 21M
```